# Count the number of directories in a list of directories

Tags: bash, find, ls, wc

I have a large number of directories, and I want to count with bash commands the number of directories in each of these directories. I am having a hard time piping `ls` and `wc` to achieve what I want.

E.g., if I have the following folder structure (where the leaf folders might contain further subfolders):

```
.
├── folder1
│   └── subfoldera
├── folder2
│   ├── subfoldera
│   └── subfolderb
├── folder3
│   ├── subfoldera
│   ├── subfolderb
│   └── subfolderc
└── folder4
    ├── subfoldera
    ├── subfolderb
    └── subfolderc
```

Then I wish to have the counts

```
1
2
3
3
```

and so on.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash and arrays:

```
dirs=(*/)                      # get all directories with globbing
                               # in current directory

for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  sub=("$d"*/)                 # get all subdirs in $d
  echo "${#sub[@]}"            # print number of array elements/subdirs
done
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
3
```

As one line:

```
dirs=(*/); for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do sub=("$d"*/); echo "${#sub[@]}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for the tip in the comment above.

Comment: To avoid problems with e.g. blanks in the names, I have fixed the code.

Comment: why does the (*/) need to be in parenthesis ?

Comment: @Akuseru: To declare `dirs` as an array and no string. See output of `dirs=(*/); declare -p dirs`.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the dirs do not contain '\n' this should work:

```
parallel 'ls -d {}/*/ | wc -l' ::: */
```

If you want to include the dir in the output:

```
parallel --tag 'ls -d {}/*/ | wc -l' ::: */
```